# Multiple assignment using map function

Tags: python

Is it possible to apply map functions to multiple values at once?

Something like this

```
from collections import defaultdict
d['a'] = [1,2,3,4]
d['b'] = [4,5,6,7]
d['a'], d['b'] = map(lambda x,y: (x,y) if x*y % 3 == 0 else (0,0), d['a'], d['b'])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-129-5191c9205e6f> in <module>()
----> 1 d['a'], d['b'] = map(lambda x,y: (x,y) if x*y % 3 == 0 else (0,0), d['a'], d['b'])

ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

It is of course possible to do this individually.

```
 l = map(lambda x,y: x if x*y % 3 == 0 else 0, d['a'],d['b'])
 m = map(lambda x,y: x if x*y % 3 == 0 else 0, d['b'],d['a'])
 d['a'] = l
 d['b'] = m

 d
 defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': [0, 0, 3, 0], 'b': [0, 0, 6, 0]})
```

Comment: you want to reassign values in place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it using `zip`. It doesn't seem very pythonic though:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
d['a'] = [1,2,3,4]
d['b'] = [4,5,6,7]
d['a'], d['b'] = zip(*map(lambda (x,y): (x,y) if x*y % 3 == 0 else (0,0),
                                                   zip(d['a'], d['b'])))
#out: defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': (0, 0, 3, 0), 'b': (0, 0, 6, 0)})
```

To get the exact output:

```
d['a'], d['b'] = map(list,zip(*map(lambda (x,y): (x,y) if x*y % 3 == 0 else (0,0), 
                                                           zip(d['a'], d['b']))))
#out: defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': [0, 0, 3, 0], 'b': [0, 0, 6, 0]})
```

Answer (score 3):

I can't think of way to make `map` function take two or more values (I hope someone'll show me it in this thread). But you can achieve exactly what you need with the help of list generators and `zip`s:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = {}
d['a'] = [1,2,3,4]
d['b'] = [4,5,6,7]
d['a'], d['b'] = [list(x) for x in zip( *[(x,y) if x*y % 3 == 0 else (0,0) for (x,y) in zip(d['a'], d['b'])])]
```

If you don't need d['a'] and d['b'] to be lists you can make the last line a little bit easier:

```
d['a'], d['b'] = zip( *[(x,y) if x*y % 3 == 0 else (0,0) for (x,y) in zip(d['a'], d['b'])])
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you're trying to do is this:

```
>>> a['b'] = None
>>> a['c'] = None
>>> a['b'], a['c'] = (1,2)
>>> a['b']
1
>>> a['c']
2
```

Yes it's possible, but you might need to have another look at what your `map` function is returning.

Answer (score 0):

If your arguments are integers or floats and your function is expressible using arithmetic standard operations you could also use arrays for that purpose

```
from numpy import array

x_vals = array([1,2,3,4])
y_vals = array([4,5,6,7])
f = lambda x,y: (x*y % 3 == 0)*x

f(x_vals,y_vals)
>>> array([0, 0, 3, 0])
```